# Why does Spring reject @Qualifier for a request-scoped bean with proxy mode INTERFACES?

Tags: spring, dependency-injection

My interface:

```
public interface SomeInterface {}
```

is implemented by a request-scoped bean:

```
@Component
@Qualifier("q")
@Scope(value = WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_REQUEST,
       proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES)
public class Implementation implements SomeInterface { }
```

Considering advice like [*INTERFACES or TARGET_CLASS: Which proxyMode should I choose?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21759684/interfaces-or-target-class-which-proxymode-should-i-choose) suggests the proxy mode `INTERFACES` should fit this pretty clean setup.

As I want to end up with several alternative implementations of `SomeInterface`, I throw in an additional `@Qualifier("q")`.

However, Spring rejects the qualifier completely, behaving as if there was no suitable `@Component` around.

For example, the following test fails with the typical `UnsatisfiedDependencyException` saying Spring "expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate", but found none for `@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=q)`.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = {SomeInterface.class, Implementation.class})
public class AutowiringTest {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("q")
    private SomeInterface cut;

    @Test
    public void autowires() {
        assertThat(cut).isInstanceOf(SomeInterface.class);
    }

}
```

In contrast, choosing the standard bean name makes the thing work:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("implementation")
private SomeInterface cut; // <-- works
```

Also, varying the standard bean name instead of adding a `@Qualifier` makes the thing work:

```
@Component("q")
@Scope(value = WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_REQUEST, 
       proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES)
public class Implementation implements SomeInterface { }
```

Also, changing the proxy mode to `TARGET_CLASS` makes the thing work:

```
@Component("q")
@Scope(value = WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_REQUEST, 
       proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class Implementation implements SomeInterface { }
```

What is so special about the proxy mode `INTERFACES` that it won't work in combination with `@Qualifier`?

Comment: Your test passes if you remove the Qualifier annotation on the Implementation class and use `@Component("q")`to set the component name. But I have no idea why it doesn't work with the qualifier, and why it does if you remove the Scope annotation.